# Java: Dice rolling and incorrect sum

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm working on a dice rolling project and am a little stuck. I'm still new to Java programming and using arrays so I'm sure I'm messing something up. The end goal is to output a table with the amount of rolls(which I have and works) and then add up the sum of the dice rolls depending on how many dice were rolled. The table works but I'm having trouble getting the sum. If I roll 4 dice I still get sums of 1-3. Could anyone give me a lead to work with? I'm stuck! ):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab1 {

    private static int N = 0;
    private static int M = 0;
    private static int total = 0;
    private static Random rnd = new Random();
    private final static int FACENUMBER = 6;
    private static int faceValue = 1;

    public Lab1() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        N = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many dice would you like to roll?"));
        System.out.println("Dice: " + N);

        M = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many times would you like to roll?"));
        System.out.println("Rolls: " + M);

        System.out.println();

        int total[] = new int[(M) + 1];

        for (int roll = 1; roll <= M; roll++) {
            total[roll] = rnd.nextInt(FACENUMBER * N) + 1;
        }

        System.out.printf("%3s%12s\n", "Rolls", "    Sum of Rolls");

        for (int k = 1; k < total.length; k++) {
            System.out.printf("%3s%12s\n", k, total[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays are addressed by index.  for example total[index].  In Java, index values start at zero (0).  Your loop "(int roll = 1 ..." skips the first value.

Comment: @DwB: That appears to be handled, if not intentional, with the `new int[(M)+1]` and `roll <= M`. Reminds me of BASIC.

Comment: If the OP is intentionally starting at 1, then this is wrong: "int k=1; k<total.length"

Comment: Rolling four 6-sided dice does not have the same distribution as rolling one 24-sided die.  You need to roll the dice individually and sum them if you want to get the correct behavior.

Comment: @DwB: No, that would be correct. The array length is one greater than M.

Comment: You are using string formatting to try to print numeric values.  Replace the `%s`'s with `%d`'s in your last `printf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
rnd.nextInt(FACENUMBER*N)+1;
```

You are getting a random number between `1` and `(FACENUMBER*N)+1`

If user inputs 10 for N, each roll your getting a number between `1` and `61`, when you actually want a number between `10` and `60`.
What you want is:

```
rnd.nextInt((FACENUMBER-1)*N)+N
```

This is not the proper way to be simulating dice though. To account for the fact that there is only one way to roll a 60 but many ways to roll other totals like 30. The following solution is better:

```
for(int roll=0; roll<N; roll++) {
  total[roll] = rnd.nextInt(FACENUMBER)+1
}
```

Comment: No, the result will still be incorrect because it doesn't have the same distribution as summing N independent rolls of the dice.